# how to create folders with sub folders using defined variables?

Tags: 16.04, bash, scripts, directory, mkdir

I have files having below formatting:

```
2017-05-01-1500-00S.SRO___001_BH_Z
2017-05-01-1543-04S.SRO___001_BH_E
2017-05-01-1543-04S.SRO___001_BH_N
2017-05-01-1543-04S.SRO___001_BH_Z
2017-05-01-1600-00S.MOG___001_SP_E
2017-05-01-1600-00S.MOG___001_SP_N
2017-05-01-1600-00S.MOG___001_SP_Z
2017-05-01-1600-00S.MYA___001_SP_E
2017-05-01-1600-00S.MYA___001_SP_N
2017-05-01-1600-00S.MYA___001_SP_Z
2017-05-01-1600-00S.SRO___001_BH_E
2017-05-01-1600-00S.SRO___001_BH_N
2017-05-01-1600-00S.SRO___001_BH_Z
```

I have made a bash scripts which have some variables listed here:

**st**  = `ls -1 2* | awk -F "[.__]" '{print $2}' | sort | uniq`

**cmp** = `ls -1 2* | awk -F "[__]" '{print $5$6}' |sort | uniq`

**day** = `ls -1 2* | awk -F "-" '{print $3}' | sort | uniq`

I want to make some folder with below formatting:

**`st`/`cmp`/`day`**

and then copy The corresponding values to its folder.

*for example files are listed below*:

```
2017-05-01-1500-00S.SRO___001_BH_Z
2017-05-01-1543-04S.SRO___001_BH_E
2017-05-01-1543-04S.SRO___001_BH_N
2017-05-01-1543-04S.SRO___001_BH_Z
```

`st=SRO`, `cmp=BHZ`, `cmp=BHE`, `cmp=BHN`, and `day=01`

so I need to make the following directory:

**first** :  `SRO/BHE/01`

**second**:  `SRO/BHN/01`

**third** :  `SRO/BHZ/01`

and then copy files containing **SRO**, **BHE**, **01** (which is `day` value) to its corresponding directory.

I hope, I have mentioned the details.

Lots of Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have a list of files in a give directory, like the ones in your question.  You want to create directories based on certain portions of those filenames, and then move those files into their appropriate directory, correct?

If so, how about this?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the list of states(?)
st=$(ls -1 2* | awk -F "[._]" '{print $2}')

# Get the list of comparisons(?)
cmp=$(ls -1 2* | awk -F_ '{print $5$6}')

# Get the day
day=$(ls -1 2* | awk -F- '{print $3}')

# Loop over all of the states(?)
for i in ${st}; do

    # Loop over all of the comparisons(?)
    for j in ${cmp}; do

        # Break te comparisons into 2 fields.  The filenames
        # have an underscore between the two fields.  The mv
        # command fails if that underscore is not included.
        cmp1=$(echo ${j} | cut -c1,2)
        cmp2=$(echo ${j} | cut -c3)

        # Loop over the days
        for k in ${day}; do
            # echo "${i}/${j}/${k}"

            # Define the sub-directory, and make it.
            sd="./${i}/${j}/${k}"
            mkdir -p "${sd}"

            # Move all files found into the appropriate sub-directory
            # Ignore any error messages since some of the string
            # combinations do not exists as files.
            mv -v 2*${k}*${i}*${cmp1}_${cmp2}* ${sd} 2>/dev/null
        done
    done
done

exit 0
```

Comment: `cmp1=$(echo ${j} | cut -c1,2)`, `cmp2=$(echo ${j} | cut -c3)` these piping was really a mistake so I removed them and every thing is fine. the directories are made fine but moving is not working at all